# Enable KMS after logging in

Tags: linux, xorg, arch-linux, kernel

Is there some way to enable KMS after booting.  My linux box is set up to log into a console,  with X having to be started manually if required.  I do not want to enable KMS on booting,  as it causes some problems in bringing up the console. So I would like to start the system without KMS and just enable it just before I start the X.  Is it possible?

I think there something called 'KMS late start',  but I can not find any info online as to how to do it.

I am using Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0):

The nVidia and AMD proprietary drivers do not support KMS, so using these in preference to the open source ones will ensure no mode setting happens at boot, but you will need to disable the open source modules in the kernel - so that means a kernel rebuild if they are not built as modules in Ubuntu.

The open source drivers can be told not to modeset during initialisation by adding:

`nomodeset i915.modeset=0 nouveau.modeset=0`

To the kernel line (this tells AMD, intel and nvidia not to mode set).  However, it may mean that X won't start.  Some of the open source drivers don't like it if modesetting is off at boot.